# Include property that is has JsonIgnore

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
public class Employee
{
    publlic string FullName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<abc> Abc { get; set; }
}
```

How can I include the property `Abc` when deserializing an object, despite having the `JsonIgnore` on it?

Comment: I feel like this is a case where you should reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3):

If the serialized data has the `Abc` property (which I assume it does, since you want to deserialize it) then create another class without the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute and deserialize the JSON as that class.

As long as you're using the `Employee` class and that attribute is present, the serializer is going to obey that attribute. That's what it's there for.

If it absolutely needs to be an `Employee` class and you can't remove the attribute, then just deserialize it as your "other" class and use that to create an instance of `Employee`.

```
var employeeWithAbc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeWithAbc>(json);
var employee = new Employee {
    FullName = employeeWithAbc.FullName, 
    Abc = employeeWithFullName.Abc }
```

But please also consider that you may be looking at the wrong problem. Why do you have `[JsonIgnore]` on that property?

Comment: like partial class right? i've tried that kind of scenario but it doesn't accept with the same property.

Comment: Not a partial class - just another class. As long as it has the correct properties the serializer doesn't care if it's one class or another. It's just going to create an instance of the class and populate it with what's in the JSON. If you need an instance of `Employee` then you can take the other class you've deserialized and use it to create a new instance of `Employee`.

Comment: i added jsonignore because i don't want the child collection object will be retrieve

Comment: @PongPagong So what are you trying to achieve?  You should state more clearly what your desired result looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Following Scott's advice, if your `Employee` class has many attributes to it, you could create separate partial classes (to avoid repeating yourself and save you from doing more work than you need to). I.e. You could have your base class `Employee` as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then you could create your other specific serialise/deserialise classes by creating a derived class of `Employee` which would then inherit the properties/attributes of `Employee`:

```
public class ParseEmployee : Employee
{
    public public List<abc> Abc
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```